# How to create a url link shortener slug that has the least amount of digits based of records in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to produce a link shortener slug (i.e. just the key, not the entire short url), that will be as short as possible, based off of how many submitted links there are in the database, on table `Link`.

I made a couple assumptions:

1- that based off of the standard characters and unreserved RFC 3986 characters, I could work in a base 66 system (26 + 26 + 10 + `'-', '_', '.', '~'`).

2- This case statement was the best way to handle setting digit size for the output link slug. I thought there would be a more elegant way to do this, but this was about the best I could come up with.

```
  def self.slug_characters(slug_digits)
    alphanumcase = [('a'..'z'), ('A'..'Z'), ('0'..'9')].map(&:to_a).flatten
    unreserved = ['-', '_', '.', '~']
    # unreserved = the balance of the RFC 3986 unreserved character set
    characters = [alphanumcase, unreserved].map(&:to_a).flatten
    (0...slug_digits).map { characters[rand(characters.length)] }.join
  end

  def self.generate_slug
    case Link.count
    when 0..66**1
      digits = 1
    when (66**1+1)..66**2
      digits = 2
    when (66**2+1)..66**3
      digits = 3
    when (66**3+1)..66**4
      digits = 5
    when (66**4+1)..66**5
      digits = 6
    when (66**5+1)..66**6
      digits = 7
    end

    self.slug_characters(digits)
  end
end
```

I was looking for some knowledge on what's permissible in a url as my understanding is somewhat cloudy from what I've been able to research.

Also, given my supplied code, I was hoping for a more elegant way to generate the slug digits count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the slug digits count, you're essentially looking for how long your number would be in base 66. This is related to calculating the logarithm of the number in base 66: the base-66 log of 1 (1 digit in base 66) is 0, the base-66 log of 66 (2 digits in base 66) is 1, the base-log of 66^2 (3 digits in base 66) is 2, etc. So `(Math.log(Link.count, 66) + 1).floor` should give you the number you're looking for.

Note that you'll run into issues if your `Link.count` is 0, but it's not clear if you'll ever run it in that situation.